# Is there a way to add Ciphers to Cygwin

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin, sshd

I currently trying to ssh into a windows computer from a linux machine.On the windows machine I have setupt a cygwin shell and am trying to connect to it through ssh. Upon doing so I get the following error.

```
>   Connection open failed; Key exchange failed (local): Cipher (client
> to server) negotied. Client algorithms are
> aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc, server
> chacha20-penssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh
```

Is there any way for me to add or update the Ciphers for cygwin? I tired updating the ssh_config and sshd_config files to no avail.

Also for an added bit of challenge, I don't have sudo access on the linux machine and can't install anything. Any solution would ideally involve not changing anything on the client side. Any bit of help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed steps as in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC150

Comment: Yeah I did. I can actually ssh into it from different computers but not this one specifically.

Comment: What is the result of using the -v flag when using ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just force it to use the right cipher using the -c flag

```
ssh -c aes128-ctr machine@your-host
```

Comment: What exactly does that mean? Is this still secure, or why doesn't the client do this by default?

Comment: Sometimes, the client will have algorithms that it can use but won't use on default. This stops it from accidentally using a depreciated algorithm in favor of a stronger one. The first three characters `aes` of each cypher method indicate the cypher method, the next three digits `128` indicate the size of the keys and last three letters `ctr` represent the mode in which the algorithm is executed. 128 bit encryption keys are more than enough to keep your connection secure although most systems opt for 256 as default nowadays

Answer (score 1):

In cygwin the default `ssh_config` file is here `/etc/defaults/etc`. I tried adding my ciphers there but for some reason it didn't work.

I had to add the ciphers to my `~/.ssh/config` using the file above as a guide